# "No such file or directory" when using ExcelWriter pointing to a server

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, pandas.excelwriter

Using Visual Studio Code.

Python 3 installed on local.

Working files stored on a server.

I am using pandas `ExcelWriter` to modify excel file.

If `ExcelWriter` points to local path then it works fine,

```
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('C:\\Users\\username\\Documents\\TestingFolder\\ExpirationList.xlsx')
```

but if I point it to a server location then it gives me an error:

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '\\01.02.03.04\\username\\Documents\\Documents\\Python\\"Expiration List report email send out"\\ExpirationList.xlsx'
```

**sample code:**

```
 import pandas as pd 
    import pyodbc 
    import smtplib 
    from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart 
    from email.mime.text import MIMEText 
    from email.mime.base import MIMEBase 
    from email import encoders 
    import datetime
    import calendar


    query = """select top 5 PolicyNumber from tblQuotes where PolicyNumber is not null"""
    conn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={SQL Server};server=servername;DATABASE=dbName;Trusted_Connection=yes;')
    df = pd.read_sql_query(query, conn)

    writer = pd.ExcelWriter('C:\\Users\\username\\Documents\\TestingFolder\\ExpirationList.xlsx') 

    #Does not work
    writer = pd.ExcelWriter('\\01.02.03.04\\username\\Documents\\Documents\\Python\\"Expiration List report email send out"\\ExpirationList.xlsx')  

    df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet1', startrow=4, header=False, index=False)
    writer.save()
```

What would be the way to use server location ?

Comment: This might not be the only issue, but for a server path you need four backslashes in front of the IP address e.g. `\\\\01.02.03.04\\...`

Comment: It was the issue. Thank you. I did not know about that. Please post an answer.

Comment: You're most welcome. Answer posted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Network/server paths need four backslashes in front of them.
E.g. `\\\\01.02.03.04\\...`

Comment: Awesome! Thank you !

Answer (score 1):

As the other answers shows, you can double the backslashes to get the right escaping. Alternatively, use a "raw" string:

```
r'\\01.02.03.04\username\Documents\Documents\Python\"Expiration List report email send out"\ExpirationList.xlsx')
```

Note that none of the backslashes are escaped in this raw string.